# Change UIImage imageOrientation metadata without affecting the image

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I have an app which loads an image from the local disk and then displays it on a UIImageView. I want to set the image to aspect scale to fit.

The problem I'm having is that the imageOrientation is coming back as UIImageOrientationRight even though it's a portrait image and that's messing with how the aspect calculations are done.

I've tried a few methods of changing the meta data but both rotate the image when it gets displayed.

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame.frame];    
NSMutableString *path =[[NSMutableString  alloc] initWithString: [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
[path appendString:@"/pic2.jpg"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

UIImage *fixed1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[img CGImage]
                        scale:1.0
                        orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];


UIImage *sourceImage = img;
UIImage *fixed2 = [UIImage
                   imageWithCGImage:[img imageRotatedByDegrees:90].CGImage
                   scale:sourceImage.scale
                   orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

iv.image = fixed1; // fixed2;

[iv setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

[self.view addSubview:iv];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I took a different approach and made the UIImageView 360 wide and placed it in the centre and this achieved the desired effect.